# Open google search results using keyboard on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

To become more efficient, I wanted to use keyboard to point to and open any google search results on the first page. I couldn't find any such shortcut. I think using tab used to work but recently it has stopped working for me.

Comment: Robino's answer in stack exchange did it for me: [Google search “go to results” keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/1103550/google-search-go-to-results-keyboard-shortcut?newreg=6987bf9cbf47469894b967a5d423f9c7)